# Excel Formula to Count

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel workbook with two sheets - `data` & `list`

I want a formula for column N of the `list` sheet that will look at columns A through M of the `list` sheet and count how many times is matched in columns A through M of the `data` sheet.

Have tried the `COUNTIFS()` function with various conditions but can't search the range.

Comment: Tried this
=COUNTIFS(data!A2:A14029,A2,data!B2:B14029,B2,data!C2:C14029,C2,data!D2:D14029,D2,data!E2:E14029,E2,data!F2:F14029,F2,data!G2:G14029,G2,data!H2:H14029,H2,data!I2:I14029,I2,data!J2:J14029,J2,data!K2:K14029,K2,data!L2:L14029,L2,data!M2:M14029,M2)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The `COUNTIFS()` function is used to calculate count according to more than one condition at the same time.
Your case is to calculate the sum of cell counts that match one condition for each column using `COUNTIF()` function.

```
=COUNTIF(data!A:A,A2) + COUNTIF(data!B:B,B2) + COUNTIF(data!C:C,C2) + COUNTIF(data!D:D,D2) + COUNTIF(data!E:E,E2) + COUNTIF(data!F:F,F2) + COUNTIF(data!G:G,G2) + COUNTIF(data!H:H,H2) + COUNTIF(data!I:I,I2) + COUNTIF(data!J:J,J2) + COUNTIF(data!K:K,K2) + COUNTIF(data!L:L,L2) + COUNTIF(data!M:M,M2)
```

The formula will help you get cell counts that match A through M of the `list` sheet in A through M of the `data` sheet.